# Space between caption and table in TeX

Tags: tables, spacing, captions

I have this code

```
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Numerical example geometry}
\label{tab_numerical_geo}
\begin{center}
\scalebox{0.9}{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
$d^A$  & $d^B$  & $d^C$  & $l^A_{12}$ & $l^C_{12}$ & $h^A$ & $h^C$ \\
\hline
-0.4434 & 0.3455 & 0.7798 & 0.1023 & 0.1523 & 0.04 & 0.023 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

I'm using `\scalebox` to reduce the size of the table, but it shrinks the space between the caption and the table. Without using it, there is a space, which is nice for my article.

Does anyone know how to reduce the size of the table while keeping that space? 
I've tried with `\footnotesize` instead of `\reducebox`, but the result was the same.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SE! Please make your code sniped as small document beginning with `documentclass{...}` and ending by `end{document}`, that it can be compiled.

Comment: scalebox does not shrink the space (but scaling the table should be an absolute last resort, and even then don't do it:-0

Answer (score 6):

Some suggestions:

- To create a bit more spacing between the caption and the tabular material, load the `caption` package and specify the desired value for the option `skip`; in the example below, I set `skip=0.5\baselineskip`.
- Don't use a `center` *environment* inside a `table`; instead, use the `\centering` *macro*.
- Since the material in the data row can, apparently, contain negative numbers, use an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment. Doing so will free you from having to type lots of `$` symbols in the header row.
- If you must use a smaller font size, don't use `\scalebox`, as doing so will create very "spindly-looking" output. Instead, use `\small` (for a 10% linear reduction of the font size) or `\footnotesize` (for a 20% linear reduction).
- For better spacing in the header and data rows, insert typographic struts.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=0.5\baselineskip]{caption}
%% define a few struts
%% (from code by Claudio Beccari in TeX and TUG News, Vol. 2, 1993)
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.9ex}}         % "top" strut
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-1.2ex]{0pt}{0pt}}   % "bottom" strut
\newcommand\TBstrut{\Tstrut\Bstrut}           % "top and bottom" strut

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Numerical example geometry}
\label{tab_numerical_geo}
\small % better than \scalebox{0.9}{...}
\centering
$\begin{array}{|*{7}{c|}}
\hline
d^A\TBstrut & d^B  & d^C  & l^{A}_{12} & l^C_{12} & h^A & h^C \\
\hline
-0.4434\TBstrut & 0.3455 & 0.7798 & 0.1023 & 0.1523 & 0.04 & 0.023 \\
\hline
\end{array}$
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to add `\bigskip` after the caption. It will add a blank line which will create a desired space.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Numerical example geometry}
\bigskip
\label{tab_numerical_geo}
\begin{center}
\scalebox{0.9}{
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Use package `caption` and `\resizebox`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
    \blindtext
    \begin{table}[!htb]
    \caption{Numerical example geometry\strut}\label{tab_numerical_geo}
    \centering
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ccccccc@{}}\toprule
    $d^A$  & $d^B$  & $d^C$  & $l^A_{12}$ & $l^C_{12}$ & $h^A$ & $h^C$ \\   \midrule
    $-0.4434$ & 0.3455 & 0.7798 & 0.1023 & 0.1523 & 0.04 & 0.023 \\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}
    \end{table}

    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Came with the same issue, I tried the `\vspace{5mm}` option. Worked easily well for me.

Comment: Simply putting `\vspace{-5mm}` solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

In lack of information, why you actually use `\scalebox`, I assume, that your document (i) has two columns, and that (ii) you will be willing to use `mdwtab` packages which enables to design nice tables ...

With this my assumptions the MWE below generate:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{mdwtab}

    \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
    \usepackage{lipsum}   

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[h]
    \footnotesize
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.5pt}
\caption{Numerical example geometry}
\label{tab_numerical_geo}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|*{7}{Mc|}}
\hlx{hvv}
d^A  & d^B  & d^C  & l^A_{12} & l^C_{12} & h^A & h^C \\
\hlx{vhv}
-0.4434 & 0.3455 & 0.7798 & 0.1023 & 0.1523 & 0.04 & 0.023 \\
\hlx{vh}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\lipsum[2-5]
\end{document}
```

option `showframe` in `geometry` package is used only to show page layout. In real-life, it had to be omitted.

**Addendum:** If you don't like to use `mdwtab` you can stick with classic tabular elements: replace `hlx{...}` with `hline` and column type `Ml` with `>{$}c<{$}`. For this column type you had to load package `array`. Of course, obtained table (to my taste) is not so beautiful.

Regarding caption: if you use package `caption`, you will obtain better spacing between caption and table without any manual adjustment.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions for typesetting the table are below. Without knowing your constraints it's difficult to be more concrete. To make sure the caption isn't getting too close to the top of the table, I've used a `\strut` at the end of the caption.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{Numerical example geometry\strut}
        \label{tab_numerical_geo}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{@{}ccccccc@{}}
        \toprule
        $d^A$  & $d^B$  & $d^C$  & $l^A_{12}$ & $l^C_{12}$ & $h^A$ & $h^C$ \\
        \midrule
        $-0.4434$ & 0.3455 & 0.7798 & 0.1023 & 0.1523 & 0.04 & 0.023 \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}
        \caption{Numerical example geometry\strut}
        \label{tab_numerical_geo2}
        \catcode`!=\active
        \def!{\phantom0}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{@{}lr@{}}
        \toprule
        $d^A$       &$-0.4434$ \\
        $d^B$       &0.3455  \\  
        $d^C$       &0.7798  \\
        $l^A_{12}$  &0.1023  \\     
        $l^C_{12}$  &0.1523  \\  
        $h^A$       &0.04!!  \\
        $h^C$       &0.023!  \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{Numerical example geometry\strut}
        \label{tab_numerical_geo3}
        \catcode`!=\active
        \def!{\phantom0}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{@{}lr@{\qquad}lr@{}}
        \toprule
        $d^A$       &$-0.4434$ &
        $d^B$       &0.3455  \\  
        $d^C$       &0.7798   & 
        $l^A_{12}$  &0.1023  \\     
        $l^C_{12}$  &0.1523   & 
        $h^A$       &0.04!!  \\
        $h^C$       &0.023!  \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, I've tried your code and there is no space between the caption and the table

Comment: If your want more space, you could add a `\medskip` after the `\caption`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put `\begin{center}` your table spec `\end{center}` after your caption in the `\begin{table}`.

Comment: Hi there. Can you make this answer more *self-contained*? By, e.g., adding a compilable  code or provide a screenshot.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.